# Problem with a tikz-uml sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-uml

I have a small problem. I want to draw 2 sequence diagrams, but I have some formatting problems.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

My solution:

```
    \documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlactor{DruckauftragA}
\umlactor[x=6]{DruckauftragB}
\umlobject[x=12]{Drucker}

\begin{umlcall}{DruckauftragA}{Drucker}
\begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragA}
\end{umlcall}
\begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragA}{Drucker}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}

\begin{umlcall}{DruckauftragB}{Drucker}
\begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragB}
\end{umlcall}
\begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragB}{Drucker}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}

\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlactor{DruckauftragA}
\umlactor[x=6]{DruckauftragB}
\umlobject[x=12]{Drucker}

\begin{umlcall}{DruckauftragA}{Drucker}
\begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragA}
\end{umlcall}
\begin{umlcall}{DruckauftragB}{Drucker}
\begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragB}
\end{umlcall}
\begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragB}{Drucker}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}
\begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragA}{Drucker}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}


\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: 1]

Link to tikz-uml.sty
http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en

Also posted in [1 http://www.golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=14492&sid=97b25a8b7fb48b70e8f623e6af5218b3](http://www.golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=14492&sid=97b25a8b7fb48b70e8f623e6af5218b3)

Comment: Please be a bit more concrete. What is your problem? What have you tried? What don't you understand? Please give a link to the `tikz-uml` package and make your code compilable if possible. I am getting 4 times "Extra \or, \end{umlcall}".

Comment: Fixed your Problem. The code needs the babel package

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, but you still do not describe your problem. I am seeing two diagrams... and?

Comment: Compare the Result picture withe the initial pictures. The "timeline" of my two threads ("DruckauftragA" and "DruckauftragB") is incorrect. In the first picture thread "DruckauftragA" must be completed before the second threads starts. In the second picture thread "DruckauftragA" started and before the thread is ended thread "DruckauftragB" started. But in my case both threads stared at the same "time". I don´t find a solution for the korrekt starttime for thread "DruckauftragB".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have no experience with this package. But without any additional information the first call of "DruckauftragB" starts at the beginning of its timeline.

You can use the option `dt` to shift the call. See the subsection "To place a call" in the [manual](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc#t-4):

> The dt option allows to place a function call on a lifeline, relatively to the last call drawn on this lifeline. It has no default value. Its unit is ex. The default behavior is to shift the call you define to avoid overwriting between to consecutive calls :

Suggestion:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, positioning} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{umlseqdiag} 
    \umlactor{DruckauftragA} 
    \umlactor[x=6]{DruckauftragB} 
    \umlobject[x=12]{Drucker} 

    \begin{umlcall}{DruckauftragA}{Drucker} 
     \begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragA} 
     \end{umlcall} 
     \begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragA}{Drucker} 
     \end{umlcall} 
    \end{umlcall} 
  %
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=25]{DruckauftragB}{Drucker} 
      \begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragB} 
      \end{umlcall} 
      \begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragB}{Drucker} 
      \end{umlcall} 
    \end{umlcall} 
  \end{umlseqdiag} 
\end{tikzpicture} 


\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{umlseqdiag} 
    \umlactor{DruckauftragA} 
    \umlactor[x=6]{DruckauftragB} 
    \umlobject[x=12]{Drucker} 
  %
    \begin{umlcall}{DruckauftragA}{Drucker} 
      \begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragA} 
      \end{umlcall} 
      \begin{umlcall}[dt=11]{DruckauftragB}{Drucker} 
        \begin{umlcall}{Drucker}{DruckauftragB} 
        \end{umlcall} 
        \begin{umlcall}[return=1]{DruckauftragB}{Drucker} 
        \end{umlcall} 
      \end{umlcall} 
      \begin{umlcall}[dt=19,return=1]{DruckauftragA}{Drucker} 
      \end{umlcall} 
    \end{umlcall} 
  \end{umlseqdiag}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tred         \umlactor[x=6, y=5]{DruckauftragB}       :-)
You are right i got no experience with that packed. I tried it the first time. But i like it ;-)
Thank you for your help